# How to create a tensorflow operation that will be reused

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have some data that I want to process before feeding/training a model. For this example I want to do a max pool 2d. I wrote a short function to do that with tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow
import tensorflow.nn as nn

def _tfMaxPool(arr, pool=(4,4), sess=None):
    op = nn.max_pool(arr, (1, 1, pool[0], 1), (1, 1, pool[0], 1 ), padding="VALID")
    op = nn.max_pool(op, (1, 1, 1, pool[1]), (1, 1, 1, pool[1]), padding="VALID")
    if sess is None:
        sess = tensorflow.Session();

    return sess.run(op)
```

The problem is this can add nodes to my graph each time, which seems to clutter my session. One alternative way is to create a model.

```
import keras

seq = keras.Sequential([ 
            keras.layers.InputLayer((1, 512, 512)), 
            keras.layers.MaxPool2D((4, 4), (4, 4), data_format="channels_first")
                     ])
def _tfMaxPool2(arr, pool=(4,4), sess=None):
    swapped = arr.swapaxes(0,1)
    return seq.predict(swapped).swapaxes(0,1)
```

The model is nearly exactly like what I want, but I think I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: I still want to know how to let an op create a layer that would be reused. The Op adds a new node to the graph every time when it was called, regardless of weather reuse=True is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you reuse your graph with various input? In the following code,tfMaxpool is defined only once.

```
def _tfMaxPool(arr, pool=(4,4)):
    op = nn.max_pool(arr, (1, 1, pool[0], 1), (1, 1, pool[0], 1 ), padding="VALID")
    op = nn.max_pool(op, (1, 1, 1, pool[1]), (1, 1, 1, pool[1]), padding="VALID")

    return op

input = tf.placeholder()
output = _tfMaxPool(input)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(output, feed_dict={input:arr1})
    sess.run(output, feed_dict={input:arr2})
```

Comment: I will try this, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.